# Play framework routes

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I want to catch all unkown GET operations.

My routes file looks like this:

```
GET     /                       controllers.MainController.index()
#All other routes

#finally
GET     /[^/]+/                 controllers.MainController.fault()
```

The final GET definition is at the bottom on the list because of the priority given to the above get operations, otherwise all requests would be true to the /[^/]+/ condition.

The problem is that it goes to the default catch page saying 'Action not found'

How can I catch all routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe

```
GET  /*route controllers.MainController.fault()
```

would work better. `route` will capture the path that was received, you can pass it as an argument to your `fault` method.

But, I would suggest another alternative: you can implement a `GlobalSettings` object where you override the method

```
def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult]
```

This method will be called each time you get a request for which it was not possible to find a proper handler. You can find more information here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal

Comment: Perfect! That did exactly what I wanted.

GET  /*route controllers.MainController.fault(route)

public static Result fault(String url){
   return badRequest(url+" not found");
}

Comment: And now, i also got it working with the custom Global class.

But the definition is a bit different:

override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader) = {
    Future.successful(NotFound(
      views.html.errorpage(request.path)))
  }